# How to explain the irregular Json with Gson,Rxjava and Retrofit

Tags: android, gson, retrofit, rx-java

Recently,I try to use Rxjava and Retrofit in my project.But I was tired of the irregular data returned by the server.For example,an interface to get a list may return:

    `[
     {"title":"title1","desc":"desc1"},
     {"title":"title2","desc":"desc2"},
     {"title":"title3","desc":"desc3"}
    ]`

and It may return:

     `{"message":"error msg","status":"failed"}`

So if I use `Observable<Response<List<Entity>>>` to parse the result,when it returns the JsonObject,it will be failed.And vice versa. 
I'm wondering how to deal with this situation.

Another interface returns the strange data is:

    `{
     "status":"success",
     "message":"success msg",
     "data":"{\"userName\":\"name\",\"userId\":\"2016\"}"
    }`

In this case,I think the `data`should be a `JsonObject`,But it returns a String,so I can not use 

    `public class HttpResponse<T>{
        private String status;
        private String message;
        private T data;
    }`
 
to parse the result.Because it can not parse the string`data` into `User`entity

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if its and object or an array using

```
if (json instanceof JSONArray) {}
```

The string problem you can fix coverting the string to json

```
JsonObject jsonData = new JSONObject(data);
```

But at the end the server should be returning to you consistent data, if you don't have control over the server try this workarounds.

Comment: Cause I use the retrofit as network framework:                                         ```Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .client(client)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();```

Comment: So these methods may not fit my situation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [OkHttp's application level interceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors) and analyze the response data by trying to parse it as the `{"message":"error msg","status":"failed"}` object and if it succeeds and `status` is indeed `failed` then you could throw an exception with proper message and if possible of proper type, that would result in Retrofit returning the thrown exception via onError notification.